# Contribution in action from collisions for a gas?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, thermodynamics

So if I write the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) for a gas:

$$ S = \int (T -U) dt \tag{1}$$
where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is potential energy.

I suspect there is a constant term (which does not affect the equations of motion) for the gas (in classical mechanics). I was hoping to verify my  <s>[paper's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1deuIYhorbMBnIRoblhe_0q1P4CkIx3DD/view?usp=sharing)  idea</s>  (There is now an updated version see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K95v8crlBWsf2_3kFiEbRDMNa5xVBdOV/view?usp=sharing)) up to equation $(19)$.The summary of ideas section wise are as follows:

$(1.1)$ We consider an arbitrary potential which $0$ everywhere until both the gas molecules collide.

$(1.2)$ Assuming a non-ideal collision (finite collision time) I get a non-zero action

$(1.3)$ We use Newton's second law to find the finite collision time and the average force is considered as pressure.

$(1.4)$ The deformed face of the molecule has an area which is also considered.

$(1.5)$ Since we are considering $2$ spheres colliding which is a function of their relative velocity we can find the average momentum change assuming the collision is not a special event.

$(1.6)$ The collision per unit 4-volume is mentioned as derived by Einstein.

Combining all the above subsections we derive a constant action term:

$$S_c = \int \frac{N R \tilde V'(2R)}{\pi}  \frac{ \langle \mu \rangle \lambda }{k_B  } dt \tag{2}$$

where $N$ is the number of particles, $R$ is the radius of the particle, $ \tilde V'(x)$ is the spatial derivative potential and $ \frac{ \langle \mu \rangle \lambda }{k_B  } $ are constants.

Is this expression correct?

Comment: (by linking to your paper you are now Less Anonymous :)